# Look for a representantion of $\zeta(s)$ and its derivative where it's valid when $s=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, special-functions, riemann-zeta

Where can I find an expression for $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta'(s)$ where it's valid for all $s$? Or at least at $s=0$.

Edit: I'm talking about the Riemann zeta function, where $\zeta(0)=-1/2$ and
$\zeta'(0)=-1/2\ln 2\pi.$

Comment: What kind of expression do you want? Have you seen Wikipedia's page about the Hurwitz zeta function?

Comment: I looked at some definitions in wikipedia but it has a restriction that Re(s) > 1. I'm looking for a definition without this restriction.

Comment: That page says "A convergent Newton series representation defined for (real) a > 0 and any complex s ≠ 1 was given by Helmut Hasse in 1930..."

Comment: See equation 21 [here] (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)